# How to describe a hypnotized state?

Tags: word-choice, videogame

I'm making a computer game. In one of the dialogs, one of the characters observes some factory workers who have been brainwashed by some alien species and drive forklifts up and down the factory yard without any sense. The character does not know what is the cause, but he's trying to describe what he sees to his friend over the phone.

I'm not a native English speaker, so I have problem getting this into a single sentence. The best I got so far is:

- "The workers just drive back and forth, like they're hypnotized."

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Requests to help rephrase a single sentence are not on-topic for us, because they are so localized and unlikely to help others in the future. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, Lauren Ipsum, I understand. I got my answer, now feel free to delete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try "in a trance":

> [trance:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trance) a half-conscious state, seemingly between sleeping and waking, in which ability to function voluntarily may be suspended.

Answer (score 2):

### Do research.

a. Find someone to hypnotize you, and then describe what you have experienced.

b. If you are afraid or don't want to go to all that trouble, find accounts of hypnotized persons.

c. If you don't know how to find those, you need to learn how to do research (which is beyond the scope of this questoon).

Comment: You misunderstood the question (or did not read through). I'm not writing this from point of view of hypnotized person, but of someone who is looking at them. I was just looking for better wording because I'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 2):

In these kind of situations I use thesauruses to look for synonyms:

- http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hypnotized